# Vector subscript out of range Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++

I'm working with matrices in C++. The task is to find odd numbers in a matrix. I created a function, but when executed with **Debug > Start Without Debugging...** I get the error:

```
Debug assertion failed. Expression: vector subscript out of range.
```

This is my code:

**File MatrixVec.h:**

```
#include "MatrixVec.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

MatrixVec::MatrixVec(int rows, int cols, int range)
{

    row.assign(cols, 0);
    mat.assign(rows, row);

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].size(); j++){
            mat[i][j] = rand() % range;
        }
    }
}

void MatrixVec::process()
{

    int *oddNum = new int(mat[0].size());
    for (int i = 0; i < mat[0].size(); i++) {
        oddNum[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[0].size(); j++) {
            oddNum[j] += mat[i][j] % 2;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mat[0].size(); i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << ". kolona " << oddNum[i]<< " neparnih elemenata." << endl;
    }
//Edit
delete[] oddNum; //forgot this line
}
```

**File MatrixVec.h:**

```
#include "Matrix.h"
#include <vector>

class MatrixVec : public Matrix {

public:
    MatrixVec(int rows, int cols, int range);
    void print();
    void process();

private:
    std::vector<int> row;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > mat;
};
```

**File Matrix.h:**

```
class Matrix {

public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual void process() = 0;

};
```

**File main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#include "Matrix1D.h"
#include "Matrix2D.h"
#include "MatrixVec.h"

using namespace std;

#define NUMBER_RANGE 10

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if (argc != 3)
    {
        cout << "Niste uneli potrebne argumente za pokretanje programa!"   << endl;
        cout << "Argumenti komandne linije treba da budu:" << endl;
        cout << "1. N dimenzija matrice" << endl;
        cout << "2. M dimenzija matrice" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    // inicijalizacija generatora nasumičnih brojeva
    srand(unsigned int(time(NULL)));

    int rowNum = atoi(argv[1]);
    int colNum = atoi(argv[2]);

    // a)
    cout << endl << endl << "a) Matrix 1D representation" << endl;

    Matrix1D mat1(rowNum, colNum, 10);

    mat1.print();

    mat1.process();

    //b)
    cout << endl << endl << "b) Matrix 2D representation" << endl;


    Matrix2D mat2(rowNum, colNum, 10);

    mat2.print();

    mat2.process();

    //c)
    cout << endl << endl << "c) Matrix vector of vector representation" << endl;


    MatrixVec mat3(rowNum, colNum, 10);

    mat3.print();

    mat3.process();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `MatrixVec`.

Comment: Where is `mat` defined and what is its full type?

Comment: `int* oddNum = new int( ... );` does not do what I think you think it does.

Comment: I'd guess mat is a vector of vectors and you'll need set the length of each mat[i] row individually in the loop, rather than just the row.assign at the start. But we'd need to see more of MatrixVec.

Comment: Can you also show us which line the problem is on? Hit 'debug' when you get the assertion and look at the call stack.

Comment: Call stack says it is this line  `int *oddNum = new int(mat[0].size());`

Comment: OK, great. That probably means that your mat vector is completely empty, i.e. there is no mat[0].

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Comment: Can you show the function where you create the `MatrixVec` variable and call the `process()` on it (presumably it is the main function)?

Comment: You gave what arguments to the program? Try the fix what I answered tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `int *oddNum = new int(mat[0].size());` actually creating one `int` with value of `mat[0].size()`. You want something like this to create an array of size `mat[0].size()`.

```
int *oddNum = new int[mat[0].size()];
```

Note: This still not answer the exact error. Seems like your `mat` vector is empty.

Comment: This is still a bad idea because their `process()` method doesn't guarantee `delete oddNum`. They should use a `vector<int>` instead.

Comment: @Dai Yea vector would be better. But also this is actually what he tries to do, but failed to express though.

Comment: I rewrite whole code, did this, changed arguments and it works now. Thank you.